# Prove that $\limsup({a_n/b_n)}$ is finite and $\sum {b_n}$ converges, then $\sum {a_n}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, limsup-and-liminf

Suppose that ${a_n}\ge 0$ and ${b_n \ge 0}$ for all n.  If $\limsup({a_n/b_n)}$ is finite and $\sum {b_n}$ converges, then $\sum {a_n}$ converges.

I spent an hour on this proof, I can't seem to figure it out. Can you guys help me?

Comment: "Suppose $|a_n| \geq 0, |b_n| \geq 0$", we don't need to assume that; it's always true.

Comment: Well that's what the question stated

Comment: Wait that's not true.  I didn't mean to put the absolute values sign for ${a_n}$ and $ {b_n}$

Comment: Since $\limsup \frac{a_n}{b_n}$ is finite, we have a uniform bound $M$ on $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$. In particular, we have $0\leq\frac{a_n}{b_n} \leq M$ for all $n$. Can you finish?

Comment: Edit: there's some problems when $b_n = 0$, but they're easy to remedy.

Comment: So do you multiply ${b_n}$ to the other side and then you have $0\le {a_n} \le M{b_n}$.  Then you say since $M{b_n}$ converges and ${a_n}$ is less than $M{b_n}$, ${a_n}$ converges?

Comment: Yup, more or less.

Comment: This is if I'm not mistaken called limit comparison test.

Comment: When ${b_n} = 0$ can we just say by the Squeeze Theorem, ${a_n} $converges to 0?

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 wait can you tell me how to solve the problem when ${b_n}=0$?

Comment: @NTT For $\lim \sup \frac{a_n}{b_n}$ to be well defined, we need the function $g(n) = \sup_{k \geq n} \frac{a_k}{b_k}$ to be well defined for large $n$, hence we need $b_n \neq 0$ for sufficiently large $n$. But $b_n$ might still be zero for finitely many terms at the start of the sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define,
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}= \lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{k\geq n}\frac{a_n}{b_n} = l.
$$
Take an $\epsilon>0$. There exists an $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$, we have,
$$
\sup_{k\geq n}\frac{a_n}{b_n}\leq l+\epsilon \implies\frac{a_n}{b_n}\leq l+\epsilon,\forall n\geq N.
$$
With this in mind, we are almost done. Notice that,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n & = \sum_{n=1}^{N-1}a_n + \sum_{n=N}^{\infty}a_n \\
& = \sum_{n=1}^{N-1}a_n + \sum_{n=N}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}b_n \\
& \leq \sum_{n=1}^{N-1}a_n + (l+\epsilon)\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}b_n \\
& < \infty.
\end{align*}

Comment: what happened if ${b_n} = 0$?